# Holonomic robots using Mindstorms

Tags: mindstorms, programming

I just got some Rotacaster wheels and want to try building a 3 wheeled Mindstorms omnibot (holonomic robot) and I'm looking for a practical (easy) discussion about writing a driving program.  I've found some theoretical papers but need something a little easier to implement.  Has anyone here built one and what advice can you give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article that may be useful:

http://botbench.com/blog/2014/05/11/omniwheel-article-in-dt-practice/

Answer (score 3):

I got also the wheels and found it really interesting... so I wrote an article were I explain all the maths and show you how to build one yourself ( instruction attached ) http://thetechnicgear.com/2014/04/howto-build-3-wheels-holonomic-robot-using-lego/

[image]

The code is for EV3 software and I will surely rewrite it for leJOS ( despite there is a class that already does the work ) on the following weeks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [excellent model at Hitechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com/models), complete with building instructions and example programs. It's for NXT, but shouldn't be very hard to adapt to EV3.